# sigqueue() to send a signal to process group

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals, sigqueue

I create process tree with fork() (about 3 child). I can easly send a signal to all of them by kill(-getpgrp(), signal_number), but how to do the same with sigqueue?

The sigqueue() function sends a signal to a process or a group of processes, they said, but unlike kill(), i can't use sigqueue() to send a signal to an entire process group by specifying a negative value in pid.

So how to do that ?

EDIT:

Code:

s1.c is a program where i "catch" the signals to take control over them.
So the couple of s1 ( with the same group id) waits for signal from sigqueue().

```
int main (int argc,char *argv[])
{   

    int i=0;
    char *do=argv[1];
    int b=atoi(argv[2]); 
    int y=fork();
    if(argc !=3)
    {
        printf("wrong arg number\n");
        exit(0);
    }

do{

switch(fork())
    {
    case -1:
            perror("error \n");
            exit(1);
            break;
    case 0:
            execl("s1","s1.c",argv[1],argv[2], NULL);
            break;
    default:
            sleep(2);
            break;
}
i++;
}
while(i<3);
    sleep(2);
    printf("ssignal %d send to gpid : %d\n",b,getpgrp());

    union sigval value;
    value.sival_int = 0;
    value.sival_ptr = 0;

    if(sigqueue(getpgrp(), b, value) == 0) {
            printf("signal sent successfully!!\n");
    } else {
            perror("SIGSENT-ERROR:");
    }
    return 0;


while(wait(0) != -1){}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: "The `sigqueue()` function sends a signal to a process **or a group of processes**..."  Where do you get that `sigqueue()` can be used to send a signal to an entire process group?  The [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigqueue.html) and [Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sigqueue.3.html) both only state a single process can be signaled.

Comment: [link](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/sigqueue.3.asp), here. Ok so how i can do that? It is possible? Many posts tell me that kill() and sigqueue() are pretty the same...

Answer (score 0):

If your implementation does in fact support process group signaling in `sigqueue`, then you probably need to do exactly [what you would do for the *pid* argument to *kill*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html):

```
sigqueue(-getprgp(), signo, value);  // Nonstandard. Remember to _negate_ the PGID
sigqueue(0, signo, value);           // Nonstandard. Shorthand to signal my own PGID
```

By the strict standard, however, you are out of luck.  `sigqueue` [supports neither the null signal (0) *nor the ability to signal groups of processes*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigqueue.html):

> The standard developers required that *sigqueue()* have the same semantics with respect to the null signal as *kill()*, and that the same permission checking be used. But because of the difficulty of implementing the "broadcast" semantic of *kill()* (for example, to process groups) and the interaction with resource allocation, this semantic was not adopted. The *sigqueue()* function queues a signal to a single process specified by the pid argument.

Comment: My implementation of `sigqueue`?It's from <signal.h> so no chance... But there's no other way to do this? Somehow pull out pid from every child that i create?

Comment: @Baal, by "implementation" I mean the platform/environment you are running on.  As for other ways to do what you want ... I'd suggest you ask a separate question on this site.